# Is there a way to organize a icon collection to allow for easy searching?

Tags: winforms, graphics, icons

Is there any way of organizing a icon collection so that it easier to find needed icons?

For example:

- the program needs a save icon
- there are 5 icons collections on your HD that have a save icon and there are 5 more collections that don't have a save icon (but you don't know that)
- do you browse through each icon collection?
- run a search (assumes files are named consistently)?

Would it be ideal to have some sort of organized directory (printable?)?

**UPDATE**

My process so far:

1. Use [XXCopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/index.htm) to merge all icon folders into one folder.
   Syntax = xxcopy "C:\Documents and Settings\jm\My Documents\Icons" "C:\Documents and Settings\jm\My Documents\All_Icons" /s /sr
2. Use [Contact Sheets](http://download.cnet.com/Contact-Sheets/3000-12511_4-10556168.html) to add all files from the super folder and then export out contact sheets for all the images.  This should sort them alphabetically.
3. Print and put in a binder -> now to find the actual file all you need to do is browse the binder, find the filename, and then search via Windows for the actual folder location.

Comment: This blog talks about a few different methods of organizing folders.
http://blog.echoenduring.com/2010/04/18/icons-and-the-web-%e2%80%93-part-3-organizing-your-icons/

Comment: Note to self -  'Contact Sheets' creator program.
http://download.cnet.com/Contact-Sheets/3000-12511_4-10556168.html

Comment: Windows XP - use print wizard found in folder to print contact sheet of 35 pictures per sheet.

Comment: The program ImageWalker seems promising as it shows thumbnails and allows exporting contact sheets but there seems to some issues as often the image thumbnails (when exporting or printing) go completely black.

Comment: Image file management - http://mgreerphoto.blogspot.com/2006/12/image-file-management.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, there is a ZIP file with icons organized in folders. The organization is mostly by filetype and image size, is pretty messy, and contains many duplicates, so you should probably not follow their example.

However, they provide a HTML file in each folder that shows the icons in that folder in a nice readable list (better than Explorer's standard preview). You could do something similar, but maybe provide a table instead, for example with one column per collection, and one row per "concept" (e.g. save icon).